# Rails fragment caching don't fetch latest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, ruby-on-rails-4, fragment-caching

I have this kind of caching

```
<% cache [obj.id, obj.updated_at] do %>
  <%= render obj %>
<% end %>
```

in `_obj.html.erb` I have

```
<% cache ["obj/#{obj.id}/logic", obj.updated_at] do %>
some logic
<% end %>
<% cache [obj.parent.id, obj.parent.updated_at] do %>
 parent's logic logic
<% end %>
```

When only the parent's data is changed, I am still getting the same cache as before. Only when obj's updated_at changed, the inner caches get updated..

Is this proper behavior? shouldn't caches inside a cached partial be handled seperatly? Or do I need to touch obj whenever I touch obj.parent?

Comment: Are you on Rails 4+?

Comment: yes, I am in rails 4.1.6

Comment: Try using `<% cache obj %>` and `<% cache obj.parent %>` instead. Assuming `obj` and `obj.parent` are instances of (or behave like) activerecord - meaning they respond to the `cache_key` method computed from `id` and `updated_at` - then the "russian doll" cache expiry should work.

Comment: why won'y creating a custom key also work? I can't use cache obj, since this is only a small part of the obj's data

Comment: Custom keys are supported. Something like `<%= cache ['homepage', obj] do %>` will allow you to cache different fragments base on the same object.

Answer (score 0):

As being said in the comments above, that's the way you should cache your fragments (`russian doll pattern`). However, it looks like you're caching just a piece of content  depending on two objects, so it should be simply `<% cache [obj, obj.parent] %>`. You do not need caching twice here, cause it has no effect.

Edit2:

```
<% cache [obj, obj.parent] do %>
  <%= render obj %> 
<% end %>
```

Comment: true, but note that inside the partial I have other caches as well

Comment: As I can see on your snippets, you only cache 'cache of cache' and nothing more. `<% cache [obj, obj.parent] %>` is exactly the same.